# Handle heavy service call with multithreading or parallel processing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Service method as mentioned below

```
GetDetails(List<int> ids)
```

The problem is that the above service method works fine if the number of ids (Count) is less than 50...anything above 50 ids throws an error... this is how the service was built and I do not have any control to change this service method...

Now I have a situation where I have to make a call to this service method for 1000 Ids which means the above service method will not work unless I am guessing to do some kind of multithreading/parallel stuff...my question is...is there a way to make this work and at the same time to not compromise with the performance a lot...any help will be deeply appreciated...

**Update**
The error is a handled exception and the service says "request cannot be handled"...this service was worked by a team which is remote and I donot have a control over it...

Comment: @user153410 your update is not realy helping, add the stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TPL + Linq. This will call the service with lists of max 50 items in parallel.

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    ids.Select((Item, Index) => new { Item, Index })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 50)
        .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Item).ToList()),
    list =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", list));
        //GetDetails(list)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> which means the above service method will not work unless I am guessing to do some kind of multithreading/parallel stuff...

Why not, using `.Take()` and `.Skip()`, loop through your list of ID's, making a call using 50 ID's at a time?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that could possibly work would be to batch your calls to the service.

```
int index = 0;
while (index < ids.Count + 50)
{
    var batchedIds = ids.Skip(index).Take(50);
    GetDetails(batchedIds);
    index += 50;
}
```